# R strip split a column in dataframe

Tags: r, regex, string, split

I have a 'data' frame, with multiple columns, one of them being 'Runtime' which has data in two formats:

```
Runtime
1 h 10 min
67 min
1 h 0 min
86 min
97 min
```

I want to convert all of them into Minutes. Have tried 'strsplit' and 'strip_split_fixed'. Can anyone show me a way to achieve my goal, split or any other method?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Is it currently a character string? Or a factor?

Comment: This is not R output. Can you provide actual R code for your example? This avoids "Oh your solution works on my example but not my actual data"

Answer (score 8):

I think I saw this kind of solution somewhere. Don't hit me.

```
df = data.frame(Runtime = c('1 h 10 min', '67 min', '1 h 0 min', '86 min', '97 min'))

df$exp <- gsub("h", "* 60 +", df$Runtime)
df$exp <- gsub("min", "* 1", df$exp)

sapply(df$exp, FUN = function(x) eval(parse(text = x)))

1 * 60 + 10 * 1          67 * 1  1 * 60 + 0 * 1          86 * 1          97 * 1 
             70              67              60              86              97
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get it one call using `gsubfn` and regex:

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn("^(?:(\\d+)\\s*h)?\\s*(\\d+)\\s*min.*$",
 ~ sum(as.numeric(x) * 60, as.numeric(y), as.numeric(z), na.rm=TRUE), x)
#[1] "70" "67" "60" "86" "97"
```

Comment: Thank you Pierre. That's really impressive. Was trying to implement your method in another problem, but stuck.
I have similar issue where, I have financial values like;
  Budget: 2.00E+07, 7.50E+07, 500000, 3.05E+07.  Not sure how should I modify your formula to get all financials in 10's

Comment: use `options(scipen=15)`. then try again

Comment: great !! Thanx. If it were not for oceans of knowledge like you, ponds like us would have dried up

Comment: Happy to help. And stop watching the nature documentaries

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you can do it:

```
# setting up your data.frame of interest
df = data.frame(Runtime = c('1 h 10 min', '67 min', '1 h 0 min', '86 min', '97 min'))



df$Runtime = gsub(' min', '', df$Runtime) # remove the min labels
hrs = grepl('h', x = df$Runtime) # which values are in an "x h y min" format?
runtime_sub = sapply(strsplit(df[hrs, 'Runtime'], ' h '), function(i) sum(as.numeric(i) * c(60, 1))) # convert the "x h y min" entries into numeric values in minutes
df$Runtime = as.numeric(df$Runtime) # convert the vector to numeric (yes, it's supposed to return a warning. Ignore it.
df[hrs, 'Runtime'] = runtime_sub # add the converted values
```

This results in:

```
  Runtime
1      70
2      67
3      60
4      86
5      97
```

Comment: absolute genius !! Thanx a lot CephBirk

Comment: No problem kash. Whichever answer you found most helpful you can upvote and/or mark with a green checkmark. This lets everyone know what you found most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Read `df[[1]]` and if the third column is NA then the first column gives the minutes; otherwise, 60 times the first column plus the third column gives the minutes:

```
with(read.table(text = as.character(df[[1]]), fill = TRUE), 
        ifelse(is.na(V3), V1, 60*V1 + V3))
## [1] 70 67 60 86 97
```

**2)** A variation is to paste "0 h" at the beginning of each component that does not have an h giving `hm` and read that computing 60 times the first column plus the third column.

```
hm <- paste(ifelse(grepl("h", df[[1]]), "", "0 h"), df[[1]])
with(read.table(text = hm), 60 * V1 + V3)
## [1] 70 67 60 86 97
```